# addEventListener to class after for loop; Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm trying to get eventlistener to work for a class created inside a loop. I can't get it to work, any suggestions?

```
window.onload = function(){
  var div = document.createElement('div'),
    container = document.getElementById('container'),
    classname = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");

  div.className = 'hello';

  var tasks = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
    'Four'
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; ++i) {
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="hello"><p>' + tasks[i] + '</p></div>';
  }

  classname.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.className = 'done';
  });

  console.log(classname);
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`classname` is a `NodeList`, `addEventListener` is a method for individual nodes. You need to loop over the elements:

```
for (i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.className = 'done';
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this worked like a charm! Will have to read up on NodeList so i can understand this :)

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, so you can not add an event listener on that. You must wanted to add event listener to the elements on this list.

So that gives:

```
//NodeList has not forEach method, but we can take it from an array
[].forEach.call( classnameElements, function( classnameElement ){
  classnameElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.className = 'done';
  });
}):
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a live NodeList, so it changes automatically when the DOM is modified.